# CodeIgniter's Scaffolding not working

Tags: codeigniter

I keep getting a 404 Page Not Found whenever I try to access CodeIgniter's Scaffolding page in  my browser, like so: localhost/codeignitor/index.php/blog/scaffolding/mysecretword

I can access localhost/codeignitor/index.php/blog just fine. I followed CodeIgnitor's instructions in their "Create a blog in 20 minutes" by storing my database settings in the database.php file; and automatically connecting to the database by inserting "database" in the  core array of the autoload.php; and I've added both parent::Controller(); and $this->load->scaffolding('myTableName') to blog's constructor. It still gives me this 404.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from CodeIgniter's [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/scaffolding.html)

> Scaffolding has been deprecated from CodeIgniter as of 1.6.0.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I wasted enough time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyAdmin is your friend. :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. I like the command line because it helps me remember the commands. However, if you type something wrong, you MAY have to type over the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

The "Create a blog in 20 minutes" tutorial missed one point.

If you check the config.php script, you'll find the following line:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";
```

I put CodeIgniter 1.7.2 to the "htdocs/ci" folder of XAMPP, so I changed this line like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/ci/";
```

If you put it to your remote web site, you may change the line like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://your_site.com/";
```

That's all. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply boxoft. Yeah, I can't seem to remember whether CI mentioned that, however I already set the base url. 
Regarding the scaffolding feature, I just wanted to learn how to populate my database using CI's scaffolding. I know I could just u

Answer (score 1):

i had the very same problem, so i fixed my base_url to this 
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php";
and now it works like a charm.
hope this helps someone in future :)

Answer (score 0):

The create a blog in 20 minutes tutorial is base on a much older version of CI - the current version won't work with the video tutorial on multiple fronts - don't waste your time.

I just went to reading the user guide, it's pretty straight forward and gave me enough to get started.